# SQL Server stored procedure parameter value as databasename

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

And to all experts here.. I'm a newbie to stored procedures.

I really need help, my problem is, is it possible to used a parameter as databasename

Below is my sample:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EventLogs]
    (@HRTable as varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    Set NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        a.*,LOG_ADDBY.ADDBY 
    FROM
        EVENT_VIEWER a
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             PK, (Lastname + ', ' + Firstname + ' ' + ExtName) as ADDBY 
         FROM 
             @HRTable.[dbo].[EMP_RECORDS]) LOG_ADDBY ON a.PerformBy = LOG_ADDBY.PK
    ORDER BY
        a.PerformDate DESC

    Set NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

`@HRTable` is my parameter.. and it returns an error.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you...

Comment: You should compose the query string dinamically and then evaluate (execute) it. Obviously you'll lose most of stored procedures performance benefits this way

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to build a view that has the table name inside it and join to that

```
SELECT 't1'as tableName ,col1, col2, col3,... from t1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 't2',col1, col2, col3,...  from t2
where
.....
and tableName=@HRTable
```

But this is not really "the done thing".  You can also use dynamic SQL & Exec if you must do this but maybe consider if you are doing whatever it is you are doing in the right way.

What's in the various tables that means you can't just put them into one?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood @HRTable is your database name.This is not gonna to work. You should use dynamic query . 
Declare Variable for query text and set it for your query then use Exec(@variable) to run the query text in variable.